# How to not set id of a table to 0 while inserting a new row

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a CMS with PHP OOP and in this CMS, admins of a site can add, edit and remove menu navigations of their website. So in order to insert a new menu navigation, I coded this class:

```
    <?php 
class Navigation
{
    private $db;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Connection();
        $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
    }
    public function NewMenu($menu_name,$menu_numbers)
    {
        if(!empty($menu_name)&&!empty($menu_numbers))
        {
            $menu = $this->db->prepare("SELECT menu_name FROM menu_nav WHERE menu_name = ?");
            $menu->bindParam(1,$menu_name);
            $menu->execute();
            if($menu->rowCount() == 1)
            {
                $notice['menu_exists'] = "Your menu already exists";
                // header("Location: addnewmenu.php?menu_name=false");
            }else{
                $ins = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO menu_nav (menu_name, menu_items) VALUES (?, ?)");
                $ins->bindParam(1,$menu_name);
                $ins->bindParam(2,$menu_numbers);
                $ins->execute();
                $notice['menu_added'] = "Menu added successfully";
                // header("Location: addnewmenu.php?menu_name=true");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfect and it correctly adds a new row into the table but what I wanted to do is to set the **id** of the table (which is unique) to a number above 0 and not 0. For example you can see in this pic that id of my *right_menu* is set to 0.

[print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lK6F9.png)

So I have to change it manually to 1 for example. I need some code that does that thing automatically and starts setting the id of my navigations from 1 !

So how can I do this?

Comment: Your id starting at 0 suggests that you're not using an AI'd column, which you should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add auto_increment to your id column

```
ALTER TABLE <yourTable> MODIFY id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```